# Any way to get inverse sine in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working on a project to solve triangles, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the inverse of sine, I've already set up switching from radians to degrees in my program I just need inverse operators.

Comment: Do you mean Math.asin() ?

Comment: So its just Math.asin(); ?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin

Comment: @haopeng I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: What does radians to degree conversion has to do with this question? Are you trying to find the inverse of sin, or degree to radian?

Comment: @Kaiido I need to know if it outputs to radians or degrees because it wont work with my algorithm if its in radians

Comment: @Kaiido It has everything to do with the question

Comment: No, it may be important for your code, but if the question is "*how do I get the inverse from `sin`?*" then `180/Math.PI` has absolutely nothing to do with it. It's like if you said to us "*I'm already able to get the sum of two numbers*" => Yes you need it, no it's not related to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use **[`Math.asin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin)**:

```
Math.asin(opposite / hypotenuse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.sin(x) takes a radian and outputs a range [-1 , 1].
Math.asin(x) takes a range [-1 , 1] and outputs a radian value.

To convert these radian values, use these two functions:

```
degreeToRadian = d => d * Math.PI * 180 ** -1

radianToDegree = r => r * 180 * Math.PI ** -1
```

For example:

```
Math.sin(degreeToRadian(30)).toFixed(3) * 1
```

results -> 0.5

or:

```
radianToDegree(Math.asin(0.5)).toFixed(3) * 1
```

results -> 30

Comment: ".toFixed(3) * 1"  is just to remove decimals